# In Perl is it possible to transform an array using another array position by position?

Tags: arrays, perl, transformation

I have an array of values which I'd like to transform using another array, like so

```
@raw_values      = qw(10 20 30 40);

@adjustment_factors = qw(1 2 3 4);


#the expected value array
@expected_values    = qw(10 40 90 160);
```

Is there a more perlish way to doing that then this?

```
for my $n (0..$#raw_values){
    $expected_values[ $n ] = $raw_values[ $n ] * $adjustment_factors[ $n ]
}
```

The arrays always have the same number of elements, and I have a few thousand to process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `map`:

```
@expected_values = map { $raw_values[$_] * $adjustment_factors[$_] } 0 .. $#raw_values;
```

Another option is to first assign the original values and then modify them:

```
@expected_values = @raw_values;
$x = 0;
$_ *= $adjustment_factors[$x++] for @expected_values;
```

Or, if you do not need `@adjustment_factors` anymore, you can empty it:

```
@expected_values = map { $_ * shift @adjustment_factors } @raw_values;
```

Comment: Excellent, just what I was looking for

Answer (score 3):

[**`pairwise`**](http://search.cpan.org/~adamk/List-MoreUtils-0.33/lib/List/MoreUtils.pm#pairwise) is the more idiomatic, [CPAN](http://cpan.org) solution.

```
use List::MoreUtils qw<pairwise>;

my @expected_values = pairwise { $a * $b } @raw_values, @adjustment_factors;
```

See [**`List::MoreUtils`**](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List%3a%3aMoreUtils)

Comment: @choroba,the outstanding "bugs" tend to follow a couple patterns. The biggest one is "Wishlist"--it's somebody's idea of something they would like MoreUtils to do, but it doesn't. The next group are things that are not officially marked as fix, but if you take a look at the thread, *a* fix was put in. And then, there are issues like if you pass the XS version a "bad array reference", you get a segfault. So, the trick is not to pass it a bad array reference. I worked at a Perl shop where a lot of guys used this mod pretty heavily.